set filepond item view follow row no wrap
default-filepond
set filepond-list > item view follow row no wrap. Only view one row no wrap. if biggest max-width then scroll follow x
View list item follow only one row.Please support me this case! I tried overwrite css filepond-preview package

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
